# Scope issues in angular modal popup

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal popup on my page. The modal popup use bootstrap angular library.

Inside the body of the modal I have a text box with ng-model attribute, and on the press of ok button I want to use that text box value.

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="ProjectName" class="form-control"  tab-index="1" required />
```

But when I log the value to console, I dont get that value.

```
$scope.ok = function () {
   console.log($scope.ProjectName);
  };
```

I have created a [plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/u9O0vgz2rvBFb2seR36O?p=preview) for debugging this. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of issues.
Firstly, you didn't define the scope property on the modal. By default, the scope is set as  child of the $rootScope.

```
 var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: size,
      scope: $scope,
      resolve: {
      }
    });
```

Secondly, you should set the ng-model to be the property of an object, otherwise angular will automatically create the property for you on the child scope.

**Controller**

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
  $scope.model = {};
   ...
}
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" ng-model="model.ProjectName" />
</div>
```

See this plunkr for working sample: http://plnkr.co/tbVHl27D2pXia19kOjob