# Angular ng-bind-html ignores ol start attribute (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ng-bind-html

I discovered this bug in my app, and wondered whether is an AngularJS bug, or I have something wrong or missing.
I have this code in two different tabs in the app, same page.

```
<div ng-bind-html="::event.description"></div>
```

In one tab, This markup is shown in a modal popup, in the other tab It is shown directly in the page inside a ng-repeat.

In event.description I have a simple ol tag with an start attribute.

```
<ol start="5">...</ol>
```

But in the popup the count starts at 1, ignoring the attribute; and in the other tab, inside the ng-repeat, the count starts in the number I set. No errors are shown in the console.

Am I missing something, or could it be a general bug and should be submitted in another place?

Comment: Are you using a modal? The scope of your pop-up could be a child of $rootscope instead of a child of the scope of the page. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375075/scope-issues-in-angular-modal-popup

Comment: Yes, but the scope is correct. I am sending correctly the markup, and then ng-bind-html renders that markup correctly, but ignores the start attribute.